# Domain of the Solution to a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{y^2}$, does the domain of the solution $y(x)$ include $x=0$?  The question came up because the initial condition given was $y(0)=2$, but based on the equation as stated, $x \ne 0$.  However, if the differential equation was rearranged as $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$, then it seems that $x=0$ is in the domain of the solution.

My specific question is whether the domain of the solution is determined based on the given equation or after we do some algebra to find and equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: This could go both ways. In a literal interpretation, singularities are those of the given equation. In a common-sense interpretation, singularities are only those that remain as such also in the explicit form of the equation.

Comment: A priori not. However, you can add it if the solution is well defined at $0$. In somehow, your equation is $$\begin{cases}y'(x)/x^2=1/y^2& x\neq 0, y(x)\neq 0\\ 2&x=0\\ something\ else& y(x)=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I would include $x=0$ in the domain. If you are prescribing  a value for $y(0)$, there is no doubt that any solution of the problem will be defined at $x=0$. The differential equality, where you do have a singularity if you replace $x=0$, is never meant to be satisfied when $x=0$. If the differential equality holds also at that point, this just means that you can extend the solution to a slightly larger interval.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your equation as $y^2 dy = x^2 dx$, you obtain the solution $y = \sqrt[3]{8+x^3}$. You can check that this function satisfies both the differential equation (for $x \ne 0$) and the initial condition. This function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, but $y'$ does have a singularity for $x=-2$ (corresponding to the singularity $y=0$ in the original equation).

Answer (score -1):

As stated, the equation cannot be satisfied if $x=0$, so the solution is assumed to have domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. However, it is entirely possible that the solution has a continuously differentiable extension to $\mathbb{R}$, and this is not encoded in the equation, but the initial condition may allow you to create such an extension. However, such an extension is not technically a solution of the equation, in the sense that these equations are assumed to be true for every differentiability point in the domain of $y$, and in this case, this would not be true for the extension.

However, in this case, one must also consider that the equation is equivalent to $y^2y'=x^2$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and additionally, the latter implies $y(0)^2y'(0)=0$, which is consistent with $y(0)=2$, as long as $y'(0)$. So the left hand side of the equation as it was originally presented can be seen as having a removable singularity at $x=0$.

Since this is a separable equation, we have that $y^2y'=x^2$, which  is equivalent to $3y^2y'=(y^3)'=3x^2$, which implies $y^3=x^3+C$. Hence $y(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+C}$, and the initial condition implies $C=8$. However, this does have a strange consequence: $x=-2$ is not a differentiability point of the domain. So the differential equation is not satisfied there.  If you are fine with the differential equation being satisfied only at the natural differentiability points, then that is perfect, but if you want to insist that the equation should be satisfied everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that every point in the domain of $y$ should be a differentiability point, then you can technically argue your equation has no solutions. The interpretation is up to you.

Comment: Downvotes without feedback are not appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I'd say it's related to your starting statement. The initial value problem involves a differential equality and an initial condition and the differential equality doesn't need to be satisfied at the point where you fix the initial condition. Therefore, the fact that $x=0$ is not in the domain of the differential equality is not a valid reason to automatically remove it from the domain of the solution.

Comment: In the theory of differential equations, a differential equation is regarded as being true everywhere in the domain of the equation, and in a proper discussion, the domain would be stated explicitly, although in this case, one can infer what the domain is supposed to be from context. Thus, it is not true that the reason I gave is not a valid reason: to the contrary, it is precisely part of what the theory is based on.

Comment: @PierreCarre Also, even if you were right, that is far from sufficient justification for warranting a downvote, especially since that much of an argument was never even stated by the downvoter. Had feedback been provided and thoroughly debunked my initial statement, I would have simply edited my answer and removed it. My answer is not of such low quality that a minor edit could not fix the problem.

Comment: You were curious on the downvote... I just provided a possible explanation. Users are not always fair, and they don't have to be. It is obvious to me that disagreements and observations should preferably conveyed as comments.

Comment: This just boils down to providing a definition of solution of a differential equation. As you know, there are several possibilities, not a single and "correct" option .

Comment: @PierreCarre This is not a matter of obligation. A person also does not need to be a good person, but this does not suddenly mean they *should not* be good people. I am voicing the lack of appreciation of unfair downvotes on my part so that people understand that they *should* provide feedback if they actually care, regardless of whether they are obligated to or not. I appreciate that you tried to give an explanation, though, even if I disagree with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131586/discussion-between-angel-and-pierrecarre).